# How can I check php version of other site just on Google Developer Console?

Tags: php, http

I want to know what php version other site is using of which I cannot access to the server.

I thought server would give the PHP version when browser communicate with server if the site is made by PHP, but I could not find that information on Network tab of Google Developer Console.
(HTTP Header)

Would you please let me know whether it is possible to know php version of other site or should I use other tool ?

Thanks for reading my question !

Comment: `curl -I <your-target-website>`, you may receive `X-Powered-By: PHP/<version>` in cased that your target is not setup this header yet.

Comment: @vietanhyt thankyou! this works. but, as you said, some website show php version and other is not.

Comment: i tried with chrome extensions, cmd ,google console, curl call but nothing revealed for other websites.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is properly configured, you should not be able to do this at all. It is often recommended, for security purposes, that the server should refuse to disclose this data at all.

If the server is not configured this way, you might be able to find the version through the response headers that you can find for any request in the network tab. Be aware, though, that there is nothing compelling the server to be truthful; it is trivial (and not problematic) for a server to lie about its backend.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on the site's configuration. I would assume most people don't want the version of PHP, or the server version in their headers. This is because it makes it faster for anyone with ill intentions to attack their webserver/website.

But you can always check if the site does return the given header :

```
$url = "https://google.com/";
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);

if (array_key_exists('X-Powered-By', $headers)) {
    echo $headers['X-Powered-By'];
}
```

Read more on the `get_headers` function in the php manual : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php